# after some time my kubernetes cluster does not work

Tags: kubernetes

I have `kubernetes` cluster.every thing work fine. but after 8 days when i run `kubectl get pods` it shows:

```
The connection to the server <host>:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have one master and one worker.
I run them in my lab without any cloud.

```
systemctl kubelet status
show **node not found**
```

my **/etc/hosts** was checked and it is correct

Comment: You need to add a lot more information. How is your Kubernetes provisioned ? Are you using Microsoft Azure or Docker for Windows or what ? Where is your Kubernetes master ?

Comment: Still very vague, how did you provision your "lab" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have lack of hardware. I run this command to solve the issue

```
sudo -i
swapoff -a
exit
strace -eopenat kubectl version
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely that the servers are rebooted. i had similar problem.
check kubelet logs on master server and take action.

if you can share the kubelet logs then we will be able to offer you further help

Answer (score 0):

Reboot itself should not be a problem - but if you did not disabled **swap permanently** reboot will enable swap again and API server will not launch - it could be first shot.

Second - check free disk space, API server will not respond if disk is full (will raise disk pressure event and will try to evict pods).

If it will not help - please add logs from Kubelet (systemctl and journalctl).

Comment: i have lack of free ram

Comment: can it create problem?

Comment: To run kubernetes master you need ~3GB of RAM and 2 CPU cores on the machine, so it could be a problem when system or other processes use memory and nothing left for K8s controlplane

Comment: i have 4 core and 8 Gb ram

Comment: i ran mongodb redis  elasticsearch on it

Answer (score 0):

verify /var/log/messages to get further information about the error

or

systemctl status kubelet

or

Alternately journalctl will also show the details.

Comment: please check the /etc/host entry . and check connecting to node from master manually. Is there a DNS server or manual host entry used

Comment: if possible share the log messages